Bound on the number of unit vectors with the same pairwise inner products
I want to know the bound on the number of unit vectors $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\langle v_i, v_j\rangle=c$ for all $i\ne j$. I know this can be upper bounded by the number of equiangular lines, but I couldn't find any finer result. Equivalently, given a set of equiangular lines, how to extract the largest set of vectors with the same pairwise inner product?

Please see whether https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203876/understanding-matouseks-proof-of-equiangular-lines answers your question (and let us know what you find).

See also https://oeis.org/A002853

@GerryMyerson This is an upper bound, if we assign a unit vector to each equiangular line, the absolute value of their pairwise inner products are the same.

See also the solution to Problem 12329 from The American Mathematical Monthly.

A bit of an aside, but the equiangular line question in complex space C^n is quite interesting. The conjecture is n^2 for all dimensions n, but this remains an important open question with implications for quantum information. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIC-POVM#Zauner's_conjecture.

From a recent newsletter: Zilin Jiang, Jonathan Tidor, Yuan Yao, Shengtong Zhang, and Yufei Zhao received the prize for “Equiangular lines with a fixed angle,” published in Annals of Mathematics in 2021.
“The authors solve a combinatorial geometry problem that has received considerable attention since the 1960s: Determine the maximum number of lines in $d$-dimensional space such that the angle between every pair is exactly $\theta$,” the citation noted. “For fixed $\theta$ and large $d$, the authors provide a sharp bound. (continued)

(continued) "The proofs combine combinatorial ideas with tools from spectral graph theory in a clever, original and elegant way.”

The upper bound is $n+1$, achieved by the vertices of a regular simplex with $0$ at the center. This is implicit in Iosef Pinelis answer, but let's state it explicitly. (It looks like the question may have been less clear at the time that Iosef answered.)
Given any $m$ vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Gram matrix is defined to be the matrix of inner products $G_{ij} = v_i \cdot v_j$. The Gram matrix is always positive semidefinite, of rank $\leq n$. Conversely, given any positive semidefinite symmetric $m \times m$ matrix $G$ of rank $\leq n$, we can find $m$ vectors $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $G_{ij} = v_i \cdot v_j$. You want your vectors to be unit vectors, so $G_{ii}=1$, and you want all pairs to have the same angles, so $G_{ij} = c$ for $i \neq j$. In other words,
$$G = (1-c) \text{Id}_m + c J_m$$
where $J_m$ is the $m \times m$ matrix which is all $1$'s.
$J$ has rank $1$, so it has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $m-1$. The remaining eigenvalue is $m$. So the eigenvalues of $G$ are $1-c$, with multiplicity $m-1$, and $cm+1-c$, with multiplicity $1$. This is positive semidefinite iff $-1/(m-1) \leq c \leq 1$. It has rank $m-1$ at $c=-1/(m-1)$, rank $m$ for $-1/(m-1) <  c < 1$, and rank $1$ at $c=1$.
The $c=1$ solution is the degenerate case $v_1 = v_2 = \cdots = v_m$. If you accept this solution, then $m$ can be as large as you like. :)
Assuming this doesn't count, we can have $m=n+1$ vectors with $c=-1/(m-1)$, or $m=n$ vectors with $-1/(m-1) <  c < 1$. The former case is the vertices of a regular simplex with $0$ at the center; the latter case is just $n$ linearly indepedent vectors.

In the case that a  $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix exists (conjecturally $n=4k,$ for all $k\geq 1,$ as well as $n=2$ ) then the bound can also be achieved by first normalizing the $\pm 1$ version of the hadamard matrix to have $+1$'s in the first column and then removing this column. This case over a simple symbol set is useful in applications.

Your post is unclear. In particular, what do you mean by "given a set of equiangular lines, how to extract the largest set of vectors with the same pairwise inner product?"? Extract from what?
Since you say "Equivalently, given a set of equiangular lines", it appears that you are missing the condition that the $v_i$'s are of the same (nonzero) length. Then, by rescaling, without loss of generality this length is $1$, and then $-1\le c\le1$. So, the Gram matrix of such vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ (with $m\ge2$) is
$$G:=(1-c)I_m+c1_m1_m^\top,$$
where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix and $1_m$ is the $m\times1$ column matrix of $1$'s. The only eigenvalues of $G$ are $1+(m-1)c$ (for eigenvector $1_m$) and $1-c$ (for eigenvectors orthogonal to $1_m$). So, $G$ is a Gram matrix iff
$$-\frac1{m-1}\le c\le1. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
So, $m$ can be any integer $\ge2$ if $c\ge0$, and
$$m\le1-\frac1c=1+\frac1{|c|}\quad\text{if }c<0.$$

These considerations have not yet involved the dimension $n$ of the ambient space. Let us now consider the role of $n$. Let $V$ denote the $n\times m$ matrix with columns $v_1,\dots,v_m$. Then $G=V^\top V$, and the ranks of $V$ and $G$ are the same. Given $G$ (that is, given $m$ and $c$ as in \eqref{1}), we can choose $V$ to be $G^{1/2}$, so that $G$ will be the Gram matrix of some vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ in $\Bbb R^m$. In this sense, it suffices to let the "ambient" dimension $n$ be $m$. On the other hand, at least when $c$ is irrational, the eigenvalues $1+(m-1)c$ and $1-c$ of $G$ will be $>0$ if they are $\ge0$, so that the rank of $V$ (which is the same as the rank of $G$) must be $m$, which implies $n\ge m$, so that $n$ is an upper bound on $m$ in this case, and this upper bound is the smallest one possible. Thus, at least when $c$ is irrational,
$$m\le
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&n&&\text{ if }c\ge0,\\
&\min\Big(n,1+\frac1{|c|}\Big)&&\text{ if }c<0.
\end{alignedat}
\right.$$
Remark: The condition that $c$ be irrational can be relaxed as follows: $c\notin C_n:=\{1\}\cup\{-\frac1{n+1-1},-\frac1{n+2-1},-\frac1{n+3-1},\ldots\}$. (The case $c=1$ is trivial.)
On the other hand, if $c$ takes the exceptional value $-\frac1{m-1}$ for an integer $m\ge2$, then, letting $(e_1,\dots,e_m)$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^m$, $\bar e:=\frac1m\sum_{k=1}^m e_k$, and
$$v_i:=\frac{e_i-\bar e}{|e_i-\bar e|}=\frac{e_i-\bar e}{\sqrt{1-1/m}},$$ we get unit vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ such that $v_i\cdot v_j=-\frac1{m-1}=c$ for distinct $i$ and $j$. Moreover, the span of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m$ (which is the orthogonal complement of the span of the vector $1_m$ to $\Bbb R^m$) is of dimension $n=m-1$. In particular, in any two-dimensional Euclidean space there are three unit vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ with angle $2\pi/3$ between any two of them. $\quad\Box$

Thanks for this bound! When I say "extract from equiangular lines", I mean that we can assign a unit vector for each equiangular line, their pairwise inner products are either $c$ or $-c$, how to choose from these unit vectors (with flipping allowed) so that we can have largest number of them with the pairwise inner product having the same sign.

The way I read this, @Iosif, is that if, say, $c=1$, then you can have any number of unit vectors, each pair of which have inner product $1$. But this is clearly false in, say, ${\bf R}^2$, where, if $|v|=1$, then the only vector $w$ with $|w|=1$ and $v\cdot w=1$ is $w=v$.

@GerryMyerson : Is your concern only about $c=1$? I think the $v_i$'s do not have to be pairwise distinct. Anyhow, the "ambient" dimension is now considered as well.

$m$ can be larger than $n$, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can find 3 such unit vectors, where the origin is at the center of an equiangular triangle and points to the vertices.

@ZiqianXie : Yes, then $c=-1/2$ is in the exceptional case $C_2$ -- see the remark at the end of the answer.

Concerning the just added last paragraph in my answer, I have only now noticed the answer by David E Speyer, which, in particular, covered this last paragraph.

If the $v_i$ do not have to be pairwise distinct, then there's nothing to stop you from taking, say, $v_1=v_2=\dotsb=v_{1000000}=(1,0)$, thereby getting a million vectors in ${\bf R}^2$.

@GerryMyerson : Of course, I agree with this. In this regard, the case $c=1$ is exceptional. However, nothing in my answer contradicts this. Indeed, as noted in the answer, $m$ can be any integer $\ge2$ if $c\ge0$ and $n$ is not fixed. And when $n$ is taken into account in the answer, the case $c=1$ excluded.
